# Windows 2012 R2 RRAS VPN Bandwidth issue (worked fine with 2008 R2)

Tags: vpn, bandwidth, rras

3 machines :
VPN Server (VS)
Random Server (RS) 
My Personnal Computer (PC)

- PC and VS on different networks
- VS and RS are on same network
- VS can connect the internet directly and has a bandwidth of 100+ Mbits
- PC can connect the internet directly and has a bandwidth of 100+ Mbits
- RS can connect the internet through VS (not using the vpn access, they are on same network) and has a bandwidth of 100+ Mbits
- PC can connect the internet through VS (using VPN) BUT bandwidth is heavily reduced : less then 1 Mbits, latency is greatly increase (+100ms instead of 10)

My vpn bandwidth is very low and I don't understand why. It's not just when I use the vpn to access the internet, it's whenever I exchange data with the VPN network and it's very problematic.

I had the very same configuration with windows 2008 R2 and i didn't have the bandwidth issue.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the vendor-provided drivers of the host machine.
Fixed everything